# SRC link changed when trying to integrate paypal button on django website

Tags: python, django, paypal, sandbox

I'm trying to add the paypal button to my django shopping site.

I have used the code from the SDK and replaced the id:

My code:

Client ID being: AWeSepzeHNW8BHE8rWPVm6CTuAGKz7SS1WzpbqEOZvQw-s_6qwFg6lxCO9MSXPpcVheUBWRgNuW6yKol

However i am receiving a 400 error.

Also viewing the page source shows the src has changed:

If you follow this link you get the following message:

throw new Error("SDK Validation error: 'Invalid query value for client-id: AabgYuFGxyzy3AbeWLPa-EtEGGreyL9bDDbWOxH4zFbPbgNc7y5yMpNO7B2NMRxCvT7-Ysou8ZXDNycT¤cy=USD'" );

/* Original Error:

Invalid query value for client-id: AabgYuFGxyzy3AbeWLPa-EtEGGreyL9bDDbWOxH4zFbPbgNc7y5yMpNO7B2NMRxCvT7-Ysou8ZXDNycT¤cy=USD (debug id: f3776258140b9)

*/

Anyone know why the src has been changed from the source to when its rendered by django?

I have followed the original src link from paypal and this, however when the page renders the link is altered.

Comment: I'm trying to add a paypal button to my web page. Using the following link as a guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/        When i insert the script tag into to my webpage as the example, it gets truncated as the description above. However it i leave out the &=currency=USD it renders just fine. Any idea why adding the currency truncates the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I had to replace the `&` with `&amp;` in the

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>
```

tag.